# when I'm in the hand pre flop am I aloud to tell the table what my cards are before I go all in *"say" *49o allin

Tags: rules, nlhe, pre-flop

playing poker online pre-flop I guess I like to show off I guess I'm just a better poker player than most as I'm the best so I mean that cash games I suck but on free tournaments I take over the king of the table hands down
with that being said pre-flop I like to tell people what my cars are say 49 offsuit and then I usually raise pretty hefty I just got blacklisted for that the girl told me that I was going to get blacked for it she says it's illegal is that true it's illegal

Answer (score 0):

this is a big NO. it could get you disqualified from a tournament or even 86ed from a poker room or loose interest iun the pot for a penalty, the rules require that you keep your hand to yourself until the hand is finished. and the floor person has no real guidelines for a penalty, so your really taking your chances. online same story, I once typed AA in a chat, and lost chat previlages for a week. at Poker stars.